# Retaining Permissions for External ext4 Drive While Reinstalling OS

Tags: permissions, users, ext4

I've had weird permissions issues getting data from HFS+ drives before, so I wanted to ask and be sure.

I boot my machine off an SSD, and have an HDD for extra data. Both are formatted in ext4. The HDD is owned by `root`, with some subfolders being owned by my user account.

If I completely wipe the SSD to reinstall the OS, but don't touch the HDD, will the `root` and my user account still be able to access the files the same way on the data HDD once re-installation is finished (given my user account has the same name)?

Or will I not be able to access the data since it was owned by the `root` user on my previous OS installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usernames play no role in unix file system permissions. Owner and group are stored as numerical ids. root always has the id 0, so on every linux (unix), if you mount your external drive, root owned files will still be root owned. This obviously will also hold true for your newly installed system.

For your user account it's a different matter. The default user in an ubuntu system usually gets the user id (uid) 1000. You can check which id you have by running `id -u` in a terminal. If you don't want to make any modifications to your external drive after reinstall, you need to make sure that your user has the same uid (and preferably gid (group id)) on the new system as on the old system. If your user has id 1000 then after reinstall it will probably be the case, too.

If your user ids differ on the new system from the old system, you can run a command like `find -user oldid -exec chown newid:groupid {} +` (or simply run `chown -R newid:groupid dir` on some direcotry) to fix permissions to your new user.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Any good reference for reading about the particulars of how these things work (I guess maybe there is a section in the POSIX spec?). Any way to ensure a certain user id when creating the new user account on reintstall?

Comment: I don't think you can influence the user id during installation. But after installation you can either modify the user id of the created user or create a new user with the desired id (`useradd`/`adduser` have parameters for specifying the user id). I don't remember any particular reference I could recommend, but I'm sure someone else can chime in here.